# How can I control the color of the text used in a magnify window?

Tags: cocoa-touch

We are using a UITextView with a dark background.  As such we have made the text white color in order to be easier to read.  The problem is the magnify window that pops up when you hold down your finger to move the insertion point uses white for the text color as well.  This makes it impossible to see exactly where the insertion point is.

Is it possible to independently control the text color used in the magnify window?

Here is a screen shot illustrating the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a quick test in here and it's working fine.

I tested with firmware 2.2.1, in the simulator and using a device.

This is what I did to test it:
1- Created a new View-Based project
2- edited the nib in the Interface Builder, added a UITextView, setting the text to white and the background to  gray, leaving everything else default

Do you have something different?

Comment: I was using a transparent background color with a UIImageView behind it.  I still dont see any way to do this with an image background like in the notes app.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it works correctly in the Notes app. Not only is the background yellow, you also see the lines.

Maybe it depends on whether you set the background color directly on the UITextView or make it transparent and set the background color of its containing view?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have any control over that.  And I think you should file a bug report with Apple over that.  It should be smarter than that.